# ¿Cómo puedo realizar la siguiente consulta?

Tags: mysql

La duda es la siguiente, tengo dos tablas, una que contiene los datos de un alumno llamada `datoaspirante` con la siguiente información...

```
nombre
apPaterno
apMaterno
familiarid
```

... con el siguiente registro:

```
nombre  apPaterno  apMaterno  familiarid
-----------------------------------------
john      doe       perez         1
```

La siguiente tabla me muestra la información de los familiares de un alumno...

```
Nombre
aPaterno
aMaterno
Parentesco
datoaspirante
```

... con los  siguientes registros...

```
    nombre  apPaterno  apMaterno  parentesco  ocupacion  datoaspirante
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    maria   perez        ghg      Madre       diseñadora       1  
    juan    doe          d        Padre       Programador      1 
    marisol lucatero     gf       Madre       Contadora        1
```

... en el cual mediante la siguiente consulta junto la información de las dos tablas para que se puedan observar la información del alumno y de sus padres.

```
select da.nombre,da.apPaterno,da.apMaterno,
f.nombre as nombrePadre,f.aPaterno as apellidoPaternoPadre,f.aMaterno as 
apellidoMaternoPadre,f.parentesco,
fa.nombre as nombreMadre,fa.aPaterno apellidoPaternoMadre,fa.aMaterno 
apellidoMaternoMadre ,fa.parentesco
from datoaspirante as da 
left join familiar as f on da.familiarid =  f.datoaspirante and f.parentesco 
= 'Padre'
left join familiar as fa on da.familiarid =  fa.datoaspirante and 
fa.parentesco = 'Madre';
```

... dándome el siguiente resultado en donde si el usuario cuenta con dos madres muestra dos veces el registro pero mostrando madres distintas.

```
nombre apPaterno  apMaterno nombrePadre apPaternoPadre  Ocupacion  nombreMadre  apellidoPaternoMadre  apellidoPaternoMadre  Ocupacion
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
john     doe        perez       juan         doe        programador   maria            perez                  ghg          Diseñadora
john     doe        perez       juan         doe        programador   marisol          lucatero               gf           Contadora
```

La pregunta es, ¿Cómo podría traerme la información del alumno y de los 3 padres en una sola columna?

Algo así:

```
nombre apPaterno  apMaterno nombrePadre apPaternoPadre  Ocupacion  nombreMadre  apellidoPaternoMadre  apellidoMaternoMadre  Ocupacion  nombreMadre2  apellidoPaternoMadre2  apellidoMaternoMadre2  Ocupacion
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
john     doe        perez       juan         doe        programador   maria            perez                  ghg          Diseñadora   marisol            lucatero       gf                      Contadora
```

Comment: No es posible con SQL, tendrías que enviar tu consulta a un lenguaje de programación como JS o PHP y desde ahí modificar tu tabla para que se muestre como quieres.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente para mostrar los datos en una sola linea utilizando subquery:

```
CREATE TABLE datoaspirante (
    nombre varchar (60) NULL,
    apPaterno varchar (60) NULL,
    apMaterno varchar(60) NULL,
    FamiliarId int NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Familia (
    nombre varchar (60) NULL,
    apPaterno varchar(60) NULL,
    apMaterno varchar(60) NULL,
    Parentesco varchar(60) NULL,
    Datoaspirante int NULL,
    Ocupacion varchar(60) NULL
)

INSERT   datoaspirante  VALUES (N'jhoe', N'doe', N'perez', 1)

INSERT Familia VALUES (N'maria', N'perez', N'mora', N'madre', 1, N'Contadora')

INSERT Familia VALUES (N'jose', N'garcia', N'feliz', N'padre', 1, N'Programador')


SELECT
CONCAT(nombre," ",apPaterno," ",apMaterno) as Aspirante,
(select CONCAT(nombre,' ',apPaterno,' ',apMaterno)from Familia where Datoaspirante=FamiliarId AND Parentesco='madre' ) as Madre,
(select CONCAT(nombre,' ',apPaterno,' ',apMaterno)from Familia where Datoaspirante=FamiliarId AND Parentesco='padre' ) as Padre,
(select Ocupacion  from Familia where Datoaspirante=FamiliarId AND Parentesco='madre' ) as Ocupacion_Madre,
(select Ocupacion   from Familia where Datoaspirante=FamiliarId AND Parentesco='padre' ) as  Ocupacion_Padre
FROM Datoaspirante
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí concatene los apellidos para que se vean mejor al usuario, pero si lo vas a reutilizar lo puedes hacer independiente.

Espero que sea útil.